Macbook Microsoft Excel 365 ODBC connection to BigQuery using Simba Driver
I am trying to connect Excel 365 to BigQuery using the Simba Driver downloaded from Google on my Macbook. I have passed the "Test" from the button on iODBC but when I try to use the connection from Excel, it either crashes or simply gives no response.
I have tried the following configurations and other parameters like SQLDialect, AllowLargeResults, LargeResultsDataSetId, etc. But still not working. I have also read the documentation from insight software to add the corresponding environment variables but still no luck.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks
# odbcinst.ini
[ODBC Drivers]
Simba ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery = Installed

[ODBC Connection Pooling]
PerfMon    = 0
Retry Wait = 

[Simba ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery]
Description=Simba ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery
Driver=/Library/simba/googlebigqueryodbc/lib/libgooglebigqueryodbc_sb64-universal.dylib
Setup=

# odbc.ini
[ODBC Data Sources]
bq_conn = Simba ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery

[bq_conn]
Driver         = /Library/simba/googlebigqueryodbc/lib/libgooglebigqueryodbc_sb64-universal.dylib
OAuthMechanism = 0
Email          = a....iam.gserviceaccount.com
KeyFilePath    = /Users/.../bigquery-service-account.json
Catalog        = project-name

Excel version: Version 16.92 (24120731)
iODBC version: 3.52.16
